# Why some times moving around face doesn't propagate to nearby triangles

Tags: modeling

I am following a pretty basic tutorial, but when I decide to make adjustment to some faces, pressing G+(X,Y,Z), for some faces the motion propagate correctly to nearby faces, while for others only the face moves away from the main body. What is happening? Are there any ways to prevent this?

[image: Red face moves incorrectly, green moves correctly]

Red face moves incorrectly, green moves correctly

[image: Example of incorrect motion]

Example of incorrect motion

Comment: You might have seperated it accidentally. Just delete that face and fill the top once again. If that doesn't work, please share your file. For that you can use blend exchange.

Comment: Thanks, is there a specific command that separate faces? Or it's something that can happen as a result of other operations?

Comment: Hitting 'P' seperates faces, but it does bring up a popup menu asking whether you want to seperate by Selection, Material or Loose Parts first and if you move the mouse off the menu nothing happens.

Comment: One command could be if you selected the top face and pressed `Y` which is _Split_ > _Selection_. But as long as the face(s) is (are) in the correct place, you do not have to delete and recreate the geometry as @TheKalaakaar suggested (especially if by accident you disassociated a more complex part of geometry consisting of more faces). Just select all by pressing `A` then `M` > _Merge_ > _By Distance_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably pressed <kbd>Y</kbd> accidentally without noticing.This separates the selected faces  without moving them out of place. Your face is then diconnected from the rest of the geometry which explains its behavior when you move it away.

You can solve this by selecting everything and press <kbd>M</kbd> then selecting `Merge by Distance`. This will merge all the vertices that are in the same location (or are really close together based on a threshold) and make you loose faces connected to the rest of the geometry again.